# How to eliminate spacing around LazyHGrid items?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-layout, lazyhgrid

I've set the spacing on the `LazyHGrid` and the `GridItems` to 0, yet there is still spacing in the *vertical* direction. Why is that? How do I eliminate that spacing?

[image]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let strs: [String] = ["aa", "", "bbbb"]
    let hgRows: [GridItem] = [GridItem(.fixed(60), spacing: 0), GridItem(.fixed(60), spacing: 0)]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text("Stuff at top").padding().frame(maxWidth: .infinity).background(Color.blue.opacity(0.5))
            Divider()
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                LazyHGrid(rows: hgRows, spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(1..<10) { i in
                        Text("B\(i).\(strs[i % strs.count])")
                            .padding().border(Color.gray, width: 1)
                    }
                }
                .padding(0)
                .background(Color.green.opacity(0.5)) // Give HGrid a green background so I can see where it is.
            }.layoutPriority(1)
            Divider()
            Spacer().layoutPriority(2)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which space are you referring to? The vertical space or the space horizontally between the items in the row?

Comment: The vertical space above, between, and below the rows.

Answer (score 0):

By adjusting the `GridItems`, it's possible to eliminate the vertical space between items:

`let hgRows: [GridItem] = [GridItem(.fixed(51), spacing: 0), GridItem(.fixed(51), spacing: 0)]`

It clearly isn't the best solution, but that's how I fixed it. I hope this answers your question.